# What did Avni Doshi try to convey towards the very end of "Girl in White Cotton" / "Burnt Sugar"?

Tags: symbolism, avni-doshi, girl-in-white-cotton

Towards the very end of her novel, Avni portrays a scene where the protagonist Antara is together with all the characters introduced in the novel (except Kali Mata). They are having a family get together. Towards the very end, her mother again starts behaving erratically. At the same time, Avni paints a picture, which can be perceived as Antara was dreaming about this whole scene. That this is not reality. For example, all the family members are singing in a language which is foreign to Antara. She is screaming and no one can hear her.

What exactly is Avni Doshi trying to convey here?